# Java Streams for looping twice over same list

Tags: java, loops, java-8, nested, java-stream

I am new to java 8, and i have a problem understanding streams for some reason. Let's say we have a list of objects List< MyObject >, where MyObject has 2 fields : Long Id, Date insertTime, and i would like to remove elements with same ID and earlier time.

With 2 for loops it is something like this :

```
for(MyObject object : myObjects) {
   for(MyObject tmpObject : myObjects) {
      if(object.getId() == tmpObject.getId()) {
         if(object.getInsertDate().after(tmpObject.getInsertDate())) 
           myObjects.remove(tmpObject);
         else 
           myObjects.remove(object);
      }
   }
}
```

How would this look when using streams?

@Michael my bad. Than i would need another list or array to store the response data.

Let's say i have

1. 1234 : 25/5/1991
2. 1235 : 25/5/1995
3. 1234 : 25/5/1999

So i need as a result

1. 1235 : 25/5/1995
2. 1234 : 25/5/1999

Thank you all.

Comment: "With 2 for loops it is something like this" I'm afraid it's not, because you can't remove from a list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: On a side note, you should *always* use `{` and `}` on your statements as it will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: @AxelH I suppose the `equals` method is the wrong place for that. The equals method should return true for the same id (and optionally the same date)

Comment: Yep @Glains, I didn't read that the date should be earlier ... so it is incorrect.

Comment: you can do somthing like below :  List<Optional<MyObj>> collect = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(MyObj::getId, maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyObj::getDate)))).values().stream().collect(toList());

Answer (score 7, accepted):

group by id and then for each id pick the one with the largest insertion date. You can replace Sample by MyObject.

```
    Map<Long, List<Sample>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getId));
    map.values().stream()
            .map(samples -> Collections.max(
                    samples, Comparator.comparing(Sample::getInsertDate)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Instead of collecting each group into a `List`, to select the maximum element in a second step, you can let the `groupingBy` operation collect the maximum element in the first place, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51132072/2711488).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so,

```
List<MyObject> latestObjects = myObjects.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getId,
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getInsertTime))),
        map -> map.values().stream().map(op -> op.orElse(null)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

First group the objects by their Id value, then reduce it to keep only the latest object for each Id value, finally collect them into a `List`.

**Update**

This can further be improved as per the comment below. Here's the augmented version of it.

```
List<MyObject> latestObjects = myObjects.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getId, 
        o -> o, BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getInsertTime))), 
            map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())));
```

Comment: Whenever the downstream collector is a reduction (i.e. all these cases where you have to deal with an `Optional` afterwards), you may use `toMap` instead of `groupingBy`: `List<MyObject> latestObjects = myObjects.stream() 
 .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen( Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getId, Function.identity(), BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getInsertTime))), map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())));`

Comment: Totally agree with you. Thanks for the invaluable feedback !