# Simulating nested for-loop filtering using Streams

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream, declarative, java-17

I'm working on a project to do with Pokemon.

I have a `PokemonRecord` record which has 2 parameters for 2 `PokemonTypes`. Any instance of `PokemonRecord` can have either 1 or 2 types. If the `PokemonRecord` has only 1 type, then `type2 == null`. The following method's purpose is to take an array of `PokemonTypes` and generate a list of all possible `PokemonRecord` type combinations that will resist all of those given types. Think of "resisting a type" as a separate method which tests a condition and returns a `boolean`.

This is a sample of the expected output:

```
Enter the name of a Pokemon type: water
Enter the name of a Pokemon type: ground
Enter the name of a Pokemon type: grass
Enter the name of a Pokemon type: done

The following type combinations resist all of [water, ground, grass]:
Grass
Normal & Grass
Grass & Ice
Grass & Fighting
Grass & Flying
Grass & Psychic
Grass & Bug
Grass & Ghost
Grass & Dragon
Grass & Dark
Grass & Fairy
Flying & Dragon
Bug & Dragon
```

Currently, my code works as intended; however, looking back, I'd like to write some things differently - in chess, when you find a good move, find a better one. I initially used a procedural for-loop approach in order to filter through the full list of `PokemonTypes` and test every single combination of them:

```java
public static List<PokemonRecord> genMonResToAll(PokemonTypes... types) {
    List<PokemonTypes> allTypes = //List of possible PokemonTypes that this Pokemon can have (PokemonTypes that are not weak to any inputted PokemonTypes)
    List<PokemonRecord> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Add any single-type Pokemon that resists all types
    for(PokemonTypes type : allTypes)
            if(new PokemonRecord(type).isResistantToAll(types))
                outputList.add(new PokemonRecord(type));

    //Add any multi-type Pokemon that resists all types
    for (int i = 0; i < allTypes.size() - 1; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < allTypes.size(); j++) {
                PokemonRecord testMon = new PokemonRecord(allTypes.get(i), allTypes.get(j));
                if (testMon.isResistantToAll(types))
                    otuputList.add(testMon);
            }
    return outputList;
}

//The functionality of any specific `Pokemon` or `PokemonTypes` method used isn't relevant, they all work as intended.
```

I'm now trying to rewrite this code to be more declarative using the `Stream` API. I was able to work out how to convert the first loop, the loop that adds single-type `PokemonRecord`, to a Stream-based declarative statement. I'm having a much harder time wrapping my head around the second. My current code with the first loop refactored is:

```java
public static List<PokemonRecord> genMonResToAll(PokemonTypes... types) {
    List<PokemonTypes> allTypes = //List of possible PokemonTypes that this Pokemon can have (PokemonTypes that are not weak to any inputted PokemonTypes)

    //Add any single-type Pokemon that resists all types
    List<PokemonRecord> outputList= allTypes.stream()
    .map(PokemonRecord::new)
    .filter(x -> x.isResistantToAll(types))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //Add any multi-type Pokemon that resists all types
    for (int i = 0; i < allTypes.size() - 1; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < allTypes.size(); j++) {
                PokemonRecord testMon = new PokemonRecord(allTypes.get(i), allTypes.get(j));
                if (testMon.isResistantToAll(types))
                    otuputList.add(testMon);
            }
    return outputList;
}

//The functionality of any specific `Pokemon` or `PokemonTypes` method used isn't relevant, they all work as intended.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PokemonRecord's are twodimensional, I don't think you should use streams. This is a better approach without streams:

1. If you havn't done this already, this is a clean implementation of PokemonRecord, which guarantees that PokemonRecord(type1, type2) == PokemonRecord(type2, type1). Preventing any illegally non-equal objects this way is generally a good idea:

```
public record PokemonRecord(PokemonType type1, PokemonType type2) {
    
    public PokemonRecord(PokemonType type1, PokemonType type2) {
        if (type1 == type2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal type combination");
        boolean order = type1 != null && (type2 == null || type1.compareTo(type2) < 0);
        this.type1 = order ? type1 : type2;
        this.type2 = order ? type2 : type1;
    }

    // your methods
}
```

2. Now just add `null` to allTypes and staircase iterate over it (to get all possible combinations without duplicates):

```
public static List<PokemonRecord> genMonResToAll(PokemonType... types) {
    List<PokemonType> allTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    allTypes.add(null);
    List<PokemonRecord> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int s = allTypes.size(), i = 0; i < s; i++) for (int j = s - 1; j > i; j--) {
        PokemonRecord record = new PokemonRecord(allTypes.get(i), allTypes.get(j));
        if (record.isResistantToAll(types)) result.add(record);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to using Streams in general, how does `PokemonRecord` being 2D mean that using Streams isn't the best implementation here? Is it because they word best with 1D data types?

Comment: @Max As far as I know, Streams are a readable and object-oriented way to get a modified version of collections. You can apply a lot of things like mappings or filters to it and collect it without changing the original collection.
To create your PokemonRecords, you will need to somehow double-iterate over allTypes. You can do this using Streams: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51131169 and then collect into a set to filter out duplicates, but you can aswell directly get all possible PokemonRecords using the method in my answer ;)